# JS background with Html text

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have found a js background and now I would like to have this background on all my php files.

The problem is that html code goes either under js or behind it. How can I solve this?

JS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
    <title>StarField</title>

    <style>

      * { margin:0; padding:0; }

      html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }

      canvas { height:10%;  width:100%; }

     
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

      const Star = function(x, y, z) {

        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;

        this.size = 25;

      };

      var context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

      var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

      var stars = new Array();

      var max_depth = 7500;

      for(let index = 0; index < 200; index ++) stars[index] = new Star(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height, index * (max_depth / 200));

      function loop() {

        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

        context.canvas.height = height;
        context.canvas.width  = width;

        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        for (let index = stars.length - 1; index > -1; index --) {

          let star = stars[index];

          star.z -= 5;

          if (star.z < 0) {

            stars.push(stars.splice(index, 1)[0]);
            star.z = max_depth;
            continue;

          }

          let translate_x = width * 0.5;
          let translate_y = height * 0.5;

          let field_of_view = (height + width) * 0.5;

          let star_x = (star.x - translate_x) / (star.z / field_of_view) + translate_x;
          let star_y = (star.y - translate_y) / (star.z / field_of_view) + translate_y;

          let scale = field_of_view / (field_of_view + star.z);

          let color = Math.floor(scale * 256);

          context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color + "," + color + "," + color + ")";
          context.fillRect(star_x, star_y, star.size * scale, star.size * scale);

        }

      }

      loop();

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Another Php file where I included js:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="feedback.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/74d89d956b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>

   <?php include "navbar.php" ?> 
   <?php include "background.php" ?> 
<div class="title">
    <h1>Thank you for being here!All suggestions are welcome.</h1>
</div>

<div class = "container">
<div class="star">
        <input type = "radio" name="rate" id="rate-5">
        <label for="rate-5" class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type = "radio" name="rate" id="rate-4">
        <label for="rate-4"class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type = "radio" name="rate" id="rate-3">
        <label for="rate-3"class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type = "radio" name="rate" id="rate-2">
        <label for="rate-2"class="fa fa-star"></label>
        <input type = "radio" name="rate" id="rate-1">
        <label for="rate-1"class="fa fa-star"></label>

        <form action = "feedbackform.php" method="post">
    <header></header>
    <div class="textarea">
        <textarea name="suggestion" cols="30" placeholder="What's your opinion about my cv?"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Css for Php file:

```
.title{
    text-align: center;

}
.title

    {
        text-transform: uppercase;
       background-image: linear-gradient(
        -225deg,
        #231557 90%,
        
        #ff1361 67%,
        #fff800 100%
      );
       background-size: auto auto;
       background-clip:border-box;
       background-size:20% auto;
       color:#fff;
       -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
       animation:textclip  2s linear infinite;
       
       
     }
     @keyframes textclip {
        to {
          background-position: 520% center;
        }
      }
    
      
  .container{
    
    text-align: center;
    width: 390px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left:750px;
    background-color: rgb(26, 24, 24);
    border: 1px solid #231557;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
    
  }
  body{
   
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
  .container > .star input{
    display: none;
  }

  .star label{
    font-size: 30px;
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    color:gray;
    transition: width 2s;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }

  input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover,
  input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover ~ label{
    color:yellow;
  }
  input:checked ~ label{
    color:yellow;
  }

  input#rate-5:checked ~label{
    color:#fe7;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(255, 255, 2);

  }
  .textarea textarea:focus{
    border-color: #444;
  }
 
 
  #rate-1:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "Bleah";
  }
  #rate-2:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "Nope";
  }
  #rate-3:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "Ok ";
  }
  #rate-4:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "Awesome ";
  }
  #rate-5:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "Magnificent ";
  }
 
  input:checked ~ form{
    display: block;
  }
  form header{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size:large;
    color:yellow;
    text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  }


  form .textarea{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    
    
  }
  form .textarea textarea{
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    background:#BEBEBE;
    color:white;
    resize: none !important;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    
  }
  
  .btn{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn button{
    width: 310px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#BEBEBE;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease 1s;
  }

  .btn button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(129, 118, 118);
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean with `The problem is that html code goes either under js or behind it.`? Why not simply put it into an external file, link it in the head element and add the `defer`-attribute to wait until the DOm structure was loaded.

Comment: If your problem is that the canvas isn't in the background, you could position it as such with this css: `canvas{
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   z-index:-1;
}`

Comment: Did you want the star canvas to be the background for the whole viewport? At the moment it only covers 10% of the screen. And did you want it to be there as the background permanently (ie when the user scrolls down?). Or did you want it just to be at the top 10% of the viewport and the following text to be over the top of it?

Comment: This is not a comment on the problem you pose but a suggestion that you are careful how much of such movement you show the user. Some people have difficulty with a lot of movement on the screen. You may like to read up about accessibility. (also it consumes quite a bit of GPU - a potential battery-flattener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the cavas which 'paints' the stars has default positioning. In this case therefore it comes before the main HTML.

If you want it as a background covering the whole viewport then a couple of things have to change:

- the height needs to go to 100%
- the positioning needs to be set at fixed (fixed in the viewport
  starting at the top left corner) and the z-index lowered so it's
  below the subsequent HTML.

In the background.php file change the style of the canvas to:

```
  canvas { height:100%;  width:100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1;}
```